# selenium rc + c# how to handle the timed out problem after runned a new browse?

Tags: c#, browser, selenium-rc

all
When I learned the selenium rc how to use selenium.click to open a new browse, I have met a problem. The new browse can be opened correctly, but the test tool NUint showed "timed out" problem, whatever I added the time, it always has the timed out problem.The whole codes as following:

```
[Test]
    public void SelectTest()
    {
        //selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome","http://www.webkey.cn/demo/docs/index2.asp?url=/demo/docs/menuselect/");
       // selenium.Start();
        selenium.Open("http://www.webkey.cn/demo/docs/index2.asp?url=/demo/docs/menuselect/");
        selenium.WaitForPageToLoad("8000");
        selenium.SelectWindow("name=main");
        selenium.Select("city","label=上海市");
        Assert.AreEqual("上海市",selenium.GetSelectedLabel("city"));

        selenium.Select("country","index=1");
        Assert.AreEqual("徐汇区",selenium.GetSelectedLabel("country"));
        selenium.SelectFrame("relative=up");
        selenium.SelectFrame("Header1");
        selenium.Click("link=首页");
        selenium.WaitForPageToLoad("10000");// This code has timed out problem.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First increase default selenium timeout(as i remeber defaulttimeout = 30000):

```
selenium.SetTimeout("90000"); // 1.5 minute
```

And second increase wait time for page load:

```
 selenium.WaitForPageToLoad("10000"); // it's only 10 seconds, 
 //increase to 60000 - one minute
```

**EDIT:**

At that i've tested all clicks done by ajax and i use followoning methiod in order to wait some element on page after redirect, so try to use this for wait redirect:

```
 public static bool WaitForElement(String waitingElement, DefaultSelenium selenium)
        {
            var isElementExists = selenium.IsElementPresent(waitingElement);
            if (!isElementExists)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(50);
                return WaitForElement(waitingElement, selenium);
            }
            else
            {
                return isElementExists;
            }
        }
```

Example:

```
 selenium.Open("/sign-up");
 WaitForElement("//input[@name='Invite']", selenium);//Wait...
```

Comment: Hi Bugai13, thanks for your reply, I do the two steps, and it also has the timed out problem. The selenium.click open another new window , at last the new website is already opened completely, why has the time out problem?

Comment: After I used Thread.sleep, the timed out problem is resolved. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
selenium.clickAndWait("link=首页");<br>
selenium.WaitForPageToLoad("60000");
```

Comment: I added the waittime to "100000", the result is "Time out".

Comment: Can you explain what are clicking in this link 首页? why are you waiting for page to load? If its public,can u share? Does that link,opens a page?